# IntelliJ-Scala - how can I import Scala-SBT project from Github to directly into IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka

I am importing my Scala-SBT projects from Github. I select

```
New
    Project from Version Controller
        GitHub
           Giving my project .git url and click clone.
```

> After it import,
>
> IntelliJ not considering as Scala-SBT project.

I saw,

```
Settings -> Build, Execution and Deployement -> SBT
```

I did not find my project, it was nil in `Linked SBT Projects`.

How can I import as Scala SBT project directly from Github.

is It mandatory that I should chack-out local and import as Scala SBT project as two steps?

**or**

can I do direct import from github.

Comment: Try checking it out separately and then following this guide to import - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-sbt.html#import_project

Comment: I gone through that page. but It importing existing project only. thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey @Sun did you tried suggestions from my answer? Just let me know if it's helpful, otherwise I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do everything as you said `File | New | Project from Version Controller | GitHub` ...

Now at this point you have bare project.

To show IntelliJ that this is SBT project open `build.sbt` file and you will see yellow alert with suggestion to `Import Project` press on it. After indexing it will be recognized as SBT one.

Answer (score 0):

I found there is no direct way to import Scala-SBT project from version control system unless your source already have IntelliJ project setup files (.idea folder in simple words). So:

1. You should clone to your local.
2. Import as Scala SBT project in IntelliJ.

**Note:** you will import Scala-SBT project into IntelliJ, but it won't consider as SBT project it treats a Java project.

I would be interested in any solution for this.